# How To Migrate AWS Elastic Search To Azure Elastic search service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, elasticsearch

Is there any way we can migrate AWS Elastic Search service to azure elastic search? If there is then how can that be done? can someone explain me the method involve in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a new cluster on Azure and after that you can migrate the data.

You can create snapshots of your indices and restore them in your elasticsearch on Azure, both clusters, the one on AWS and the one on Azure, will need to be able to read from the snapshot repository.

You can also use a logstash node to consume from your cluster on AWS and send to the cluster on Azure, also, the logstash node needs to be able to communicate with both clusters.

Comment: Can you share us some documentation for this? I am just in the starting phase of the migration and dont have much knowledge can you help us more on this.